# Why a quantitative researcher might not use purposive sampling?

Tags: sampling

I am aware that qualitative researchers use purposive sampling. However...will you please explain why a quantitative researcher might not use purposive sampling?

Comment: I am not sure what the word "purposive" means.  If you are refering to a form of nonrandom sampling the researcher should use a form of random sampling in order to make valid inferences..

Comment: Purposive sampling means selecting people on purpose because they can best provide information to answer the research question.

Answer (score 0):

Because in quantitative research the respondent is not an informant but a representative. We want the sample to be a representation of the population
 If we pick and choose who is in the sample, then that is no longer given.